# TypeError with requests.get in python?

Tags: python, request

I have been working with PyCharm Community edition 2016.3, I have a line in my code

```
''' ------other stuff-------'''
def getReply():
    getResponse = requests.get(getRequestURL, data, headers=server_headers)
'''--- other stuff----'''
```

I provide my credentials(data)and the header file.. It works perfectly fine with PyCharm, but when I try to run it in terminal with Python version 2.7.5, I keep getting an error :-

```
getResponse = requests.get(getRequestURL, data, headers=server_headers)
TypeError: get() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: But `requests.get()` doesn't take a second positional argument, it only takes one. It's not clear to me if this is the `data` parameter or the `auth` parameter.

Comment: Most of all, your claim that things worked in *PyCharm* threw me here, your code wouldn't work when run in PyCharm either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`requests.get()` only takes **one** positional argument, the URL. Everything else is must be keyword argument, including authorisation data:

```
getResponse = requests.get(getRequestURL, auth=data, headers=server_headers)
```

This assumes you wanted to set the `auth` basic auth argument. I note that this would not have worked in PyCharm *either*.